# Synchronized collection that blocks on every method

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a collection that is commonly used between different threads. In one thread I need to add items, remove items, retrieve items and iterate over the list of items.  What I am looking for is a collection that blocks access to any of its read/write/remove methods whenever any of these methods are already being called. So if one thread retrieves an item, another thread has to wait until the reading has completed before it can remove an item from the collection.

Kotlin doesn't appear to provide this. However, I could create a wrapper class that provides the synchronization I'm looking for. Java does appear to offer the synchronizedList class but from what I read, this is really for blocking calls on a single method, meaning that no two threads can remove an item at the same time but one can remove while the other reads an item (which is what I am trying to avoid).

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: "this is really for blocking calls on a single method, meaning that no two threads can remove an item at the same time but one can remove while the other reads an item" No, that's not how `synchronizedList` works.

Comment: In Java, a `synchronized`  method  locks on the  _object_, blocking other threads from calling _any_ `synchronized` method on that object (not just the same method).

Comment: But there are posts that state that synchronization isn't available when iterating over items. Is that true?

Comment: @Sweeper Yet the official docs on synchronizedCollection states this: "It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when traversing it via Iterator," - That means that iterating is not synchronized.

Comment: @Johann That is correct. Iteration is not synchronised, but that's not what you said.

Comment: @Sweeper But I did say that. I clearly indicated that reading items (which is part of iterating) is something I want synchronized. I don't want to read an item in a loop while another thread is removing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper such as the one returned by [`synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-)
synchronizes calls to every method, using the wrapper itself as the lock. So one thread would be blocked from calling `get()`, say, while another thread is currently calling `put()`. (This is what the question seems to ask for.)

However, as the docs to that method point out, this does nothing to protect *sequences* of calls, such as you might use when iterating through a collection. If another thread changes the collection in between your calls to `next()`, then anything could happen. (This is what I think the question is really about!)

To handle that safely, your options include:

1. **Manual synchronization**. Surround each sequence of calls to the collection in a [`synchronized`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html) block that synchronises on the collection, e.g.:

```
val list = Collections.synchronizedList(mutableListOf<String>())
// …
synchronized (list) {
    for (i in list) {
        // …
    }
}
```

This is straightforward, and relatively easy to do if the collection is under your control. But if you miss *any* sequences, then you could get unexpected behaviour. Also, you'll need to keep your sequences short, to avoid holding the lock for an extended time and affecting performance.

2. **Use a concurrent collection implementation** which provides primitives letting you do all the processing you need in a single call, avoiding iteration and other sequences.

For maps, Java provides very good support with its [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface, and high-performance implementations such as [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). These have methods allowing you to iterate, update single or multiple mappings, search, reduce, and many other whole-map operations in a single call, avoiding any concurrency problems.

For sets (as per [this question](/questions/6992608/why-there-is-no-concurrenthashset-against-concurrenthashmap)) you can use a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), or you can create one from a `ConcurrentHashMap` with  [`newKeySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet--).

For lists (as per [this question](/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk)), there are fewer options. (I think concurrent lists are much less commonly needed.) If you don't need random access, [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) may suffice. Or if modification is much less common than iteration, [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) could work.

There are many other concurrent classes in the [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, so it's well worth looking through to see if any of those is a better match for your particular case.

3. If you have specialised requirements, you could **write your own collection implementation** which supports them. Obviously this is more work, and only worthwhile if none of the above approaches does what you want.

In general, I think it's well worth stepping back and seeing whether iteration is really needed. Historically, in imperative languages all the way  from FORTRAN through BASIC and C up to Java, the `for` loop has traditionally been the tool of choice (sometimes the *only* structure) for operating on collections of data — and for those of us who grew up on those languages, it's what we reach for instinctively. But the functional programming paradigm provides alternative tools, and so in languages like Kotlin which provide some of them, it's good to stop and ask ourselves “What am I ultimately trying to achieve here?” (Often what we want is actually to update all entries, or map to a new structure, or search for an element, or find the maximum — all of which have better approaches in Kotlin than low-level iteration.)

After all, if you can tell the compiler *what* you want to do, instead of *how* to do it, then your program is likely to be shorter and easier to read and maintain, freeing you to think about more important things!